# I am unable to launch my terminal in vscode

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I recently started messing around with a raspberry pi but did not use VSCode at all during that time.

I launched VSCode today and found that I was no longer able to launch the integrated terminal. Trying to do so shows the panel, hides the panel, then gives the following error:

> The terminal process command
>   'C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe' failed to
>   launch (exit code: {2}).

That path is correct, so I am not sure how to fix this error.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled VSCode twice and cleared all Workspaces completely.

Comment: Does Windows PowerShell work when launched outside of VSCode?  What are the contents of your user `settings.json`?  What is the relevance of the Raspberry Pi?  There is a [recent issue on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/88008) with that same error.

Comment: PowerShell does work outside of VSCode. The settings.json are default from a fresh install. My work with the Raspberry Pi was the only thing that I know of between a working terminal and a not working terminal. It may not be relevant. I looked at that issue but the setting it referred to did not affect the error.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this was reinstalling Windows, as unfortunate as it was.