# Integrated Terminal fails to launch

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, terminal

When opening a new terminal, VScode will briefly display the integrated terminal and then close it with an error message:

`The terminal process command 'C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe' failed to launch (exit code: {2})`

This error first happened when I tried to open the terminal while in a folder located in a different drive from cmd and powershell, but seems to happen in C: as well. The terminals function outside of VScode. This error occurs even when running the application as an administrator.

Things I have tried:

- Adding `"terminal.integrated.windowsEnableConpty": false` to my `settings.json`
- Changed it to run the cmd prompt instead
- Deleted 'C:\Users\Name\AppData\Code'
- Reinstalled
- Restarted my computer
- Running `SFC /scannow`

Here is my `settings.json`:

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": -1,
    "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "editor.fontFamily": "'Roboto Mono', monospace",
    "editor.cursorBlinking": "expand",
    "zenMode.hideLineNumbers": false,
    "zenMode.hideTabs": false,
    "zenMode.hideStatusBar": false
}
```

Comment: What does "when I tried to open the terminal from a different drive" mean?  How are you launching VSCode?  Recent question with the same error message: [when I tried to open the terminal from a different drive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60131550/150605)

Comment: When I open VScode and go to 'File > Open Folder' I am opening a folder in a different drive. Then I run the terminal and it errors.

Comment: Also, I am not looking to reinstall windows ;)

Comment: If these are indeed the same issue then it's good to link them together.  Also, the posted answer was not the only relevant point raised on that question.

Comment: Looking through the other posts, the solutions provided don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, whitelisting the folder `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code` in my anti-malware program fixed the problem for me. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

Exit code 2 is "The system cannot find the file specified." Windows does keep a copy of important files and there is a tool to replace the missing and corrupt files.

1) Open the command prompt as Administrator
2) Type **SFC /scannow**
3) After the scan completes reboot your machine.

Comment: This produced an error: https://gyazo.com/80d17be235c6eac71f4b58be304b6992

After restarting the machine, the issue is not fixed.